# Ubuntu 18.04, fresh install, cannot install build-essential!

Tags: dependencies, gcc

I downloaded a  *fresh* copy of ubuntu 18.04.2 installation disc (yes I did the md5 checksum of the image before making the bootable USB disk).

I then installed it on an old laptop.

I had an old installation of 14.04 on it, but I formatted the `/` partition (but not `/home` `/opt/` partition), so there was no old libraries or binaries around, and install the new ubuntu 18.04 on the *formatted* `/` partition, but then mounted the old `/home` and `/opt`. Pretty standard stuff. When installing, I chose "download all updates" after installing, which I take is just doing `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`.

I then boot into the new installation. I did a

```
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
build-essential : Depends: gcc (>= 4:7.2) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: g++ (>= 4:7.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is a *fresh* installation and I could not install build essential!
`aptitude install build-essential`
throw up some none-sense errors like this

```
Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 is installed
```

Not to be daunted, I tried a simpler fare:

```
apt-get install gcc
Depends: gcc-7 (>= 7.3.0-12~) but it is not going to be
```

installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

But of course, I have gcc-8 installed!

```
aptitude install gcc
libtsan0 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 is installed
liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 is installed
libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 is installed
```

I tried to install the basic numerical package lapack

```
aptitude install liblapack3
libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 is installed
```

There must be something really broken in ubuntu's end.
`My /etc/apt/sources.list` is pristine, and has only these lines not 
commented off:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

I've been using Ubuntu as my primary os for over 14 years, since 5.04 days, but never seen anything like this before. I thought by doing a fresh installation (rather than upgrade) on a LTS 
version would be relatively safe...

Any help would be greatly appreciated by this very confused user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`sudo apt-get update`
to update your package list.
Then

`sudo apt-get autoclean`
to clean up any partial packages.
Then

`sudo apt-get clean`
to clean up the apt cache.

`sudo apt-get autoremove`
will clean up any unneeded dependencies.

If while doing this you can identify the broken package this code will very forcefully remove it.

`sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq build-essential`

[source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=947124)

Comment: This didn't work for me.  also, the OP clearly edited his file.  I have never opened mine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figure out my own mistake. The problem is my /etc/apt/sources.list Somehow when I was trying editing the settings, the bionic-updates section got commented out! Now I restored them and did an apt-get update &apt-get upgrade and everything is fine now. I can install all the build-essentials just fine.

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusions I caused!