# Dependency error installing build-essential

Tags: 18.04, dependencies, vmware, gcc

In recently istalled Ubuntu 18.04.4 on SSD hard disk and Intel Core i5-6500 I've try to install build-essential with this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  build-essential: Depends: dpkg-dev (> = 1.17.11) but will not install
```

If I try to install dpkg-dev, also several dependencies are shown. I've try to solve dependecies everyway (update, upgrade, clean, autoclean, autoremove) and reinstall with apt, apt-get, -y, ... even uncomenting the bionic-updates section in /etc/apt/sources.list as is said in [Ubuntu 18.04, fresh install, cannot install build-essential!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128051/ubuntu-18-04-fresh-install-cannot-install-build-essential), but the same error persists.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: To your question above, please add the complete output of `sudo apt update` and of `apt-cache policy dpkg-dev` and of `sudo apt install dpkg-dev`

Comment: Try using `aptitude` to install the package. Aptitude will try to resolve dependencies for you. Please read [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1155019/968501)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 1):

I solved adding `bionic-updates` and `bionic-security` lines to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

So, my `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like:

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: worked for me. got me around the " libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.35-0ubuntu3) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed"
 problem with cmake.